# How can I Detect "'something.exe' has stopped working" from another program in C# on Windows 7?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-7

I am currently writing a program that among other things, is attempting to track whether a series of other programs close with the Windows 7, "Whatever.exe has stopped working" window popping up.  I do not have access to the code for these other programs.  I am working in C#.  Any help or ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you open the application that you want to check if has stopped working from C# code?

Comment: Might get logged to the eventlog. Or you could enum windows and search for that specific one

Comment: @ctabuyo Unfortunately, no.

Comment: @Marged I will look into trying something like that and let you know. The other programs have their own logging I can dig into as well, but messaging changes from implementation to implementation, so I can't trust that to be consistant. The event logs might work though. Thanks.